# What is origin/META in Git?

Tags: git

I am new to Git, so maybe this is not a good question.

On remote origin there is a META branch, is it something that we usually find in a Git repository? What is it used for?

Comment: I’d guess that someone just created a branch called “META” on that repository, which is why you’re seeing it. The only internal name Git uses is “HEAD”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Such a branch is usually not present.

If you do a plain `git init`, the only branch being created will be `master`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Meta information for the project/repo. But GIT never creates such a branch by its own.

Use https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git/goto to learn about GIT in less than 15 Minutes. Worth every minute.